# API for PhotoSwipe V4 UI

Tags: photoswipe

Is there a single function call when the Phottoswipe UI elements are used by a user? I'd need to update a PHP session last activity time and need to tap into the PhotoSwipe UI. I can update the session when the user clicks on a thumbnail, but once the PhotoSwipe is fired, user might zoom, click on share button, go to full screen, or hit the close button. All of these are user activities that should keep a session alive. Going to next or previous slide also needs to update the session.

From the documentation I don't see any API for this, but is there a place in the code where one can intercept ALL of the UI activities?

By the way, the new version has greatly improved the previous one thanks to [Dmitry Semenov](http://dimsemenov.com/) rewrite of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API of UI, as UI is built just via public API of PhotoSwipe.

```
photoSwipeInstance.framework.bind(document, 'pswpTap click', function(e) {
   // tap or click
   // can trigger twice (if touch device)
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. If understand this correctly any user interaction with the UI will trigger this since they either have to touch the screen or click on it. That is except for keyboard shortcuts such as Esc, etc. Is that right? And if so do you have a suggestion how to intercept that? Many thanks again.